# Sum, validate, and plot monthly inventory levels

Tags: python, performance, beginner, pandas, matplotlib

The idea is that I have a subset of the movements of material of a factory (over 700k rows), and I want to separate these movements by the reference of each product to plot the stock of each product over time.

But the dataframe has repeated days, and the stock at the end of every month (`STOCK FINAL`) is in another dataframe (`inventario_df`). I get the `final_stock` from the other dataframe because I wanted to see if the data from the two dataframes are the same (in the 1st output it is not the same, in the 2nd it is, so now I know that the company has some kind of problem with the reference of the 1st output).

**example data**:

MvtosMaterial.xlsx:

```
Referencia  Fecha       Stock
13017094    20170507    23857.00
13037094    20170507    10733.00
13127094    20170101    10.00
13127094    20170101    20.00
13127094    20170101    0.00
14017094    20170507    9395.00
14047094    20170507    88847.00
15017094    20170507    10157.00
```

Inventario.xlsx:

```
AÑO_INVENTARIO  MES_INVENTARIO  REFERENCIA  STOCK FINAL
2017            1               13017094    17644
2017            1               13037094    5948
2017            1               13127094    10558
2017            1               14017094    15502
2017            1               14047094    44453
2017            1               15017094    10214
2017            5               13017094    17962
2017            5               13037094    3588
2017            5               14017094    13970
2017            5               14047094    88066
2017            5               15017094    8830
```

And the **intended output** is the groups separate by the reference, summing the quantities of stock by day, and the last day of each month with a final stock. This value is taken from the other dataframe (`inventory_df`), so one of the output groups would be:

```
        Referencia  Fecha       Stock       Stock_final
101673  1304790     2015-01-05  135746.0    0.0
101745  1304790     2015-01-07  129353.0    0.0
101834  1304790     2015-01-08  182706.0    0.0
...
103123  1304790     2015-01-29  140634.0    0.0
103213  1304790     2015-01-30  194103.0    0.0
103226  1304790     2015-01-31  193383.0    253039.0
103306  1304790     2015-02-02  187932.0    0.0
103382  1304790     2015-02-03  182183.0    0.0
...
```

and another group:

```
        Referencia  Fecha       Stock   Stock_final
51804   13017287    2016-05-26  2000.0  2000.0
51805   13017287    2016-06-23  1764.0  1764.0
51806   13017287    2016-10-19  1586.0  0.0
51807   13017287    2016-10-24  1200.0  1200.0
51808   13017287    2017-01-19  1079.0  0.0
51809   13017287    2017-01-20  938.0   0.0
...
```

**code**:

```
import pandas as pd
path = '../Data/'
mvtos_material_df = pd.read_excel(path + 'MvtosMaterial.xlsx')
inventario_df = pd.read_excel(path + 'Inventario.xlsx')
mvtos_material_df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(mvtos_material_df['Fecha'], format='%Y%m%d')
inventario_df = inventario_df.rename(index = str, columns = {'MES_INVENTARIO': 'Month', 'AÑO_INVENTARIO': 'Year'})
inventario_df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(inventario_df[['Year', 'Month']].assign(Day=1), format='%Y%m%d')
inventario_df.drop(['Month', 'Year'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

mvtos_dict = {}
stock_finales = {}
mvtos_material_df['Stock_final'] = 0.0

for name, group in mvtos_material_df.groupby('Referencia'):    
    mvtos_dict[str(name)] = pd.DataFrame()
    # for loop to fill moves_dict with the orders per day
    for k, v in group.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Fecha', freq='M')):
        if not v.empty:
            # Comparing dates in inventory and movements to get the final stock
            a = (inventario_df[inventario_df['REFERENCIA'].values == v.tail(1)['Referencia'].values])
            a = (a[a['Fecha'].dt.month.values == v.tail(1)['Fecha'].dt.month.values])
            a = (a[a['Fecha'].dt.year.values == v.tail(1)['Fecha'].dt.year.values])        

            # sum all days together and create the ones which are missing
            for i, j in v.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Fecha', freq='D')):            
                temp = j.tail(1).copy() # We need to get the last row 
                mvtos_dict[str(name)] = mvtos_dict[str(name)].append(j.tail(1))            
            if not a.empty:
                # Drop last row (last day of the month) and add the one with the final stock
                mvtos_dict[str(name)].drop(mvtos_dict[str(name)].index[len(mvtos_dict[str(name)])-1], inplace = True)                            
                temp['Stock_final'] = float(a['STOCK FINAL']) 
                mvtos_dict[str(name)] = mvtos_dict[str(name)].append(temp)
```

In the code I have now, I have separated the groups in a dictionary so that I can access them later. Although I mainly used the dictionary because I didn't know how to do all this in the same dataframe.

On the second group, the first 2 rows are the last days of each month because they didn't have any other move between on `mvtos_material_df`.

Also, for **plotting** the graphs I use this code:

```
for ke, v in mvtos_dict.items():
    x = v['Fecha']
    y1 = v['Stock']
    y2 = v['Stock_final'].replace(0, np.nan)

    # I had to use this to fix a problem with the axis
    # but now seems is not needed
    #pd.plotting.deregister_matplotlib_converters()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 8))
    ax.plot(x, y1, c='red',alpha=0.6, label='Movimientos de material')
    ax.scatter(x = x, y = y2, alpha=1, marker='x', label='Stock Final')

    ax.xaxis.grid(True)
    myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d")
    start, end = ax.get_xlim()
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, 30))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

    ## Rotate date labels automatically
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    ax.set_title(f'Gráfica del componente {ke}')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of what this code accomplishes, including example inputs and the intended output.

Comment: @200_success done, ty for taking the time to check it

Comment: I think what would help your question greatly is a better title. You should change your title to state what the code achieves (group references by something) and just state your current code with example data. In addition, asking about whether or not code is correct or for specific changes to the code are off-topic here. However, asking for general improvements is on-topic. Any reviewer will most likely give you a more vectorized version anyways (but they might also comment on other things).

Comment: @Graipher ty for the input, I'll try to rework the post to include all the code, the example data is better to put it here or with a link to a gist? Because I was thinking that I could share a big chunk of data instead of only 10 rows but here I think it will be too much

Comment: @set92 A few rows is usually enough (as long as all relevant parts are there, e.g. at least two groups and two entries per group/enough for the function to work.

Comment: I think is good now, the only thing may be the intended output, which I've put as two separate groups, and I don't really mind if there are separate or I have them all together in a dataframe and then I can filter by reference to plot them

Comment: @Graipher why offtopic? I didn't put all the code, the input and intended output? Or is a problem of my english and the ability to state what I want to do?
I rewrite to a mostly vectorized code, going from 43s to 12s, but now I have a multi-index dataframe which seems harder to work with.

Comment: @set92: Sorry, I had cast my close vote some time ago, long before your edit. I think the current version is much better than the previous (and I have therefore voted to reopen the question). One thing left to change could be the title. Maybe something like `"Plot stock movements per product and day and cross-check with end-of-month inventory"` better describes what your code achieves (and not what you want out of a review)?